# How would I make sure all collision detections are ran before the next game tick is run?

Tags: javascript, timing

So, I have a collision detection function that I use on all "Debris" sprites. I loop over each "Debris" sprite, and call that function. The problem is, is sometimes the game doesn't have enough time to detect the touch of a "bullet" sprite, before it zooms away from the sprite, not touching it. I'm not sure how to fight against this, other than maybe making the bullet go slower, which I'd rather not be forced to do. This is part of my "bullet" code:

```
    document.addEventListener("gameLoop", function () {
      for (var l = 0; l < bullets.length; l++) {
          (function () {
              var n = bullets[l]
              syncPosition(n)
              n.drawSprite()
              move(n, n.speed)
              n.distanceCount += n.speed //n.speed = 30
              if (n.distanceCount > 500) {
                  deleteSprite(n, l)              }
          })()
      }
    })
```

This is part of my "debris" code:

```
  document.addEventListener("gameLoop", function () {
      for (var l = 0; l < debris.length; l++) {
          (function () {
              var n = debris[l]
              var y = 0
              if (tickCount % 30 == 0) {
                  n.speed = (Math.random() + .5) * 2
              }
              if (!freezeDebris) {
              var y = n.element.style.top.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'');
              y = Number(y)
              y += n.speed
              if (y <= window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) {
                  y += "px"
                  n.element.style.top = y
              } else {
                  deleteSprite(n, l)
              }
            }
              if (detectTouch(n, bullets)) {
                  deleteSprite(n, l)
              }
```

This is an example of what I'm seeing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpv4R.jpg

And if you need more context, this is my whole project:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eSGxBPHy2cWASaxYUW3TivtirRyZm5Xy?usp=sharing

Comment: Run your game loop twice more often and slow everything 2x down.

Comment: I think you should use https://repl.it instead of google docs.